# Read from StreamReader doesn't reach the end - Using Telnet protocol

Tags: c#, telnet

I am using Telnet protocol in order to query UNIX servers and get the output of some commands. I am using the [Minimalistic telnet from code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19071/Quick-tool-A-minimalistic-Telnet-library) and I did a slight modification to enable reading output to the end of the stream:

```
public void WriteCommand(string cmd)
{
    using (NetworkStream stream = tcpSocket.GetStream())
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.AutoFlush = true;

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                 string message = cmd;
                 writer.WriteLine(message);
                 writer.Flush();

                 while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                 {
                     string response = reader.ReadLine();
                     Console.WriteLine(response);
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

The problem is that when I run this method, which is supposed to return the output till the end, it's blocked because it is not recognizing the end of stream, so the condition `reader.EndOfStream()` is never reached.

Can you tell me what's the problem with my code please?

Comment: Could it be that you have some odd characters in your stream and read line is not reading it correctly?

Comment: Telnet connections aren't like HTTP; the connection remains open. What are you expecting to indicate the end of the stream? Are you terminating the connection?

Comment: No, I want to terminate the command, but I want the connection to stay opened

Comment: As @itsme86 suggests, you are probably not reaching the end of the stream. Your `tcpSocket` is declared elsewhere, so I'm guessing that's a connection that you keep open. If the connection is still open, you've not reached the end of the network stream!

Comment: @Marko No I don't have odd caracters into my commands

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to examine the stream in Wireshark.  Some additional diagnostics might shine some light on the issue.

Comment: @itsme86 I see what you mean... I didn't close the connection that I am opening so the output stream will not reach the end... Is there anyone that I can detect the end of a command and not the end of the stream ?

Comment: @HamdiBaligh Telnet commands are usually submitted by pressing ENTER, so you could break your stream up using combinations of \r and \n as delimiters. Also, make sure you implement the telnet protocol completely (e.g. special considerations for 0x255) or you'll probably end up with some garbage and/or unintended input. RFC854 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc854) is a great resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @itsme86 wrote the connection remains open. Do you expect any response from the commands being send? If true then read the response, parse it, find some delimiter or other finish symbol which will mark that command has been executed successfully and break you while().